# using js to parse log and filter out something

Tags: javascript

I am quite new in javascript and I am trying to parse the log and filter out something. The log looks like:

```
v=5,ci=3,si=60,sv=1,ss=active,es=-,ai=a23-369b-4da3-b2da-630aee75f8c5,ip='99.114.107.39',rm=GET,rv=HTTP/1.1,rs=200,rt=0.787020,rr='/tag/febe1eab436e98eb4ed3711870496c91/st.js?l=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.michaels.com%2Fv
```

The output should be printed by splitting on `,`, line by line and also filter out something that I don't need. e.g, I only need `ip` and `rr` attributes, so the output should look like:

```
ip='99.114.107.39'
rr='/tag/febe1eab436e98eb4ed3711870496c91/st.js?l=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.michaels.com%2Fv
```

The code I have is following, but it doesn't work:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>reading file</title>
    <script>
        function readText(obj){
            var file = obj.files[0],
            div=document.getElementById('main');
            if(file){
                div.innerHTML='';
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onerror = function(event){
                    div.innerHTML='The file can\'t be read! Error ' + event.target.error.code;
                }
                reader.onload = function(event){
                    var cont = event.target.result.split(',');
                    for(var i=0; i<cont.length; i++){
                        var name = cont.split('=');
                        if (name[0]==="rr") {
                            div.innerHTML+=cont[i]+'<br />';
                        }

                    }
                }
            reader.readAsText(file);
            }
        }

    window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById('ff').onchange=function(){readText(this);}
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="ff" />
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript's `split()`:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3x2s/)

**Example:**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var text = "v=5,ci=3,si=60,sv=1,ss=active,es=-,ai=a23-369b-4da3-b2da-630aee75f8c5,ip='99.114.107.39',rm=GET,rv=HTTP/1.1,rs=200,rt=0.787020,rr='/tag/febe1eab436e98eb4ed3711870496c91/st.js?l=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.michaels.com%2Fv";

    var ip = '',
        rr = '';
    var splits = text.split(',');

    for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
        if (splits[i].indexOf('ip') > -1) 
            ip = splits[i];
        else if (splits[i].indexOf('rr') > -1)
            rr = splits[i];
    }

    document.getElementById('divIp').innerHTML = ip;
    document.getElementById('divRr').innerHTML = rr;

};
```